# Creating a dumb component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if there is any difference in performance when dealing with dumb component in React, since there are 2 possible ways to achieve the same result.

```
function Comp(props) {
    ...
} 

const Comp = props => {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a good question. I created a comparison: https://jsperf.com/react-stateless-compare

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's definitely no difference between the two in your example. Hence this code also gets compiled and you end up having the same thing:

```
function CompA(props) {}
const CompB = props => {}
```

gets transpiled to:

```
function CompA(props) {}
var CompB = function CompB(props) {};
```

edit: There is difference in both functions tho. In performance they are the same but in behavior the code is different. We have hoisting and different context involved.

edit2: Well, it looks like there IS a difference. Check out https://jsperf.com/react-stateless-compare

Comment: There is a difference: Hoisting. `function` gets hoisted, `const` dosn't.

Comment: Also, arrow functions bind `this` to the surrounding scope - performance-wise, there's probably not any significant difference, but it's incorrect to say that they compile to the exact same code!

Comment: That is true but the question was about performance. There is no difference in the performance.

Comment: I added a line at the end to clarify.

Comment: There is a difference: https://jsperf.com/react-stateless-compare

Comment: @GergelyFehérvári what about the transpiled version? how does `var CompB = function CompB(props) {};` perform? I guess most people are still transpiling even though chrome doesnt need it!

Comment: @GergelyFehérvári that is really weird https://jsperf.com/react-stateless-compare-2 I would love to get an explanation why it is faster.

Comment: This is because the V8 engine implementation. On the other hand, I think we should not care about this performance differences, but good to know, that there is. I think the question should be reopened, because there is a difference, and therefore I can answer properly, as I was about to, but it got closed.

Answer (score 1):

Really they are two ways to define a function and there should be no difference in the performances.